# Antd Forms, get values from custom component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, antd, react-props

I'm trying to add some custom components within `getFieldDecorator` and obtain the values onCreate added. Not sure how I can go about it since the state is found within the Custom components. Ideally, the custom component will handle all user input value but unsure about how to pass those values as part of the object onCreate.

```
import React from "react";
import { Icon, Modal, Form, Input } from "antd";
import Tags from "./EditableTagGroup";

const Taskform = Form.create({ name: "event_form" })(props => {
  const { visible, onCancel, onCreate, form } = props;
  const { getFieldDecorator } = form;

  const handleCreate = () => {
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }

      form.resetFields();
      onCreate(values);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      title="Task"
      closeIcon={
        <Icon
          type="close"
          style={{ fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: "600", marginTop: "30px" }}
        />
      }
      okText="Create"
      onCancel={onCancel}
      onOk={handleCreate}
    >
      <Form layout="vertical">
        <Form.Item label="Name">
          {getFieldDecorator("name", {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please type the name of task!"
              }
            ]
          })(<Input placeholder="Write a task name" />)}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Description">
          {getFieldDecorator("description")(
            <Input.TextArea
              style={{ minHeight: "60px" }}
              autoSize={{ minRows: 3, maxRows: 6 }}
              placeholder="Write a description"
            />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>{getFieldDecorator("tags")(<Tags />)}</Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </Modal>
  );
});

export default Taskform;
```

[image: Edit laughing-morning-rwktl]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your code on sandbox. You may need to pass the props `getFieldDecorator` down to the `EditableFormTag.js` like below:

Step one: from the `taskform.js`

```
<Form.Item><Tags getFieldDecorator={getFieldDecorator} /></Form.Item>
```

Step two: Inside the `EditableTagGroup.js`

```
const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;

{inputVisible &&
    <Input
        ref={this.saveInputRef}
        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onPressEnter={this.handleInputConfirm}
        value={inputValue}
        onBlur={this.handleInputConfirm}
        type="text"
        size="small"
        style={{ width: 78 }}
    />
}

{getFieldDecorator("tags", {
        initialValue: { tags }
    })(
        <Input
            ref={this.saveInputRef}
            type="text"
            size="small"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
    )
}
```

End result

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: By any chance you know where to make the changes to treat tags as an array? I'm assuming changes need to be made in Taskform? Since EditableGroupTag tags is already an array

Comment: let me take a look at the code again. i will get back to you shortly. i may need to pass another props `setFieldsValue` along with the one passed alreadt

Comment: So I simply need to pass the getFieldDecorator to any component in order to link my custom components to the form?

Comment: Yes bro. That's the solution.